# calculate total value of an order with jQuery in a Nested-Form in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I've a form to create a bill. The different articles for that bill can be added with the nested_form gem for rails.

Now I want to update the "total amount" value everytime I change the article or the count of the articles.

My problem is: how can I access the different attributes in the nested form?

Hope someone can help me.

My _forms.html.erb:

```
<%= nested_form_for @bill do |f| %>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <%= link_to 'x', bills_path, :class => "close", "data-dismiss" => "modal" %>
        <% if @current_method == "edit" %>
            <h3>Rechnung bearbeiten</h3>
        <% else %>
            <h3>Rechnung anlegen</h3>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
  <% if @bill.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@bill.errors.count, "Fehler") %> trat beim Speichern auf:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @bill.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Rechnungsdatum</label>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.date_select :date %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kunde</label>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.collection_select :customer_id, Customer.all, :id, :name_company_id %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Artikel</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <%=f.fields_for :bill_items do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'bill_item_fields', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.link_to_add "Artikel hinzufügen", :bill_items, :class => "btn btn-success", :style => "color:#fff" %><br>
      <small>(1 Einheit entspricht 30 min)</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Rabatt</label>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field number_with_precision(:discount, :precision => 2), :class => "input-mini", :style => "color:red", :placeholder => "0.00" %> &euro;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><div style="font-weight:bold;">Gesamtpreis</div></label>
    <div class="controls"><div style="font-weight: bold;"><%= number_with_precision(@bill.total, :precision => 2) %> &euro;</div></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <% if @current_method == "edit" %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Bezahlt</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.check_box :state, :id=>"ch_location" %></div>
  </div>
      <% end %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kategorie</label>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.select :category, %w{CMD Lindau}, :class => "input-mini" %></div>
  </div>
  </div>
        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= link_to 'Schliessen', bills_path, :class => "btn", "data-dismiss" => "modal" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Speichern',  :class => "btn btn-primary", :style => "color:#fff", :disable_with => "Speichere..." %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and the particl _bill_items_field.html.erb:

```
<%= f.text_field :count, :class => "input-mini calc", :placeholder => "Anzahl", :id => "item_quantity" %>
<%= f.collection_select :article_id, Article.all, :id, :name_and_price, :id => "item_price" %>
Löschen? <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
<br><br>
```

EDIT:
I think the field ":name_and_price" has to be parsed with an regex? At the Moment it looks like "NAME (x.xx €)"

edit: HTML Code:

```
<body>

<!-- Navigation
    ================================================== -->
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/bills/43" class="edit_bill" id="edit_bill_43" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Ft2ry9QwRVEITjDRxt8b99OfVKHbaoiLkyotblgeJ9g=" /></div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="/bills" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
            <h3>Rechnung bearbeiten</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Rechnungsdatum</label>
    <div class="controls"><select id="bill_date_1i" name="bill[date(1i)]">
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select id="bill_date_2i" name="bill[date(2i)]">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="bill_date_3i" name="bill[date(3i)]">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option selected="selected" value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kunde</label>
    <div class="controls"><select id="bill_customer_id" name="bill[customer_id]"><option value="1" selected="selected">#Schnell Adrian - CMD (ID 1)</option>
<option value="6">#Hans Gustav - Test2 (ID 6)</option></select></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Artikel</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="fields">
        <input class="input-mini calc" id="item_quantity" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][0][count]" placeholder="Anzahl" size="30" type="text" value="22" />
<select id="bill_bill_items_attributes_0_article_id" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][0][article_id]"><option value="1">iOS (35.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="2">Webdesign (25.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="3">Beratung (50.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="6" selected="selected">Anfahrt (0.8 &euro;)</option></select>
Löschen? <input name="bill[bill_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="bill_bill_items_attributes_0__destroy" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<br><br>
<input id="bill_bill_items_attributes_0_id" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="54" /></div><div class="fields">
        <input class="input-mini calc" id="item_quantity" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][1][count]" placeholder="Anzahl" size="30" type="text" value="2" />
<select id="bill_bill_items_attributes_1_article_id" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][1][article_id]"><option value="1" selected="selected">iOS (35.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="2">Webdesign (25.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="3">Beratung (50.0 &euro;)</option>
<option value="6">Anfahrt (0.8 &euro;)</option></select>
Löschen? <input name="bill[bill_items_attributes][1][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="bill_bill_items_attributes_1__destroy" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][1][_destroy]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<br><br>
<input id="bill_bill_items_attributes_1_id" name="bill[bill_items_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="56" /></div>      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success add_nested_fields" data-association="bill_items" data-blueprint-id="bill_items_fields_blueprint" style="color:#fff">Artikel hinzufügen</a><br>
      <small>(1 Einheit entspricht 30 min)</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Rabatt</label>
    <div class="controls"><input class="input-mini" id="bill_discount" name="bill[discount]" placeholder="0.00" size="30" style="color:red" type="text" value="15" /> &euro;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><div style="font-weight:bold;">Gesamtpreis</div></label>
    <div class="controls"><div style="font-weight: bold;">72.60 &euro;</div></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Bezahlt</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input name="bill[state]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input checked="checked" id="ch_location" name="bill[state]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Kategorie</label>
    <div class="controls"><select id="bill_category" name="bill[category]"><option value="CMD" selected="selected">CMD</option>
<option value="Lindau">Lindau</option></select></div>
  </div>
  </div>
        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="/bills" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Schliessen</a>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Speichere..." name="commit" style="color:#fff" type="submit" value="Speichern" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form><div data-blueprint="&lt;div class=&quot;fields&quot;&gt;
        &lt;input class=&quot;input-mini calc&quot; id=&quot;item_quantity&quot; name=&quot;bill[bill_items_attributes][new_bill_items][count]&quot; placeholder=&quot;Anzahl&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; /&gt;
&lt;select id=&quot;bill_bill_items_attributes_new_bill_items_article_id&quot; name=&quot;bill[bill_items_attributes][new_bill_items][article_id]&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;1&quot;&gt;iOS (35.0 &amp;euro;)&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;2&quot;&gt;Webdesign (25.0 &amp;euro;)&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;3&quot;&gt;Beratung (50.0 &amp;euro;)&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value=&quot;6&quot;&gt;Anfahrt (0.8 &amp;euro;)&lt;/option&gt;&lt;/select&gt;
Löschen? &lt;input name=&quot;bill[bill_items_attributes][new_bill_items][_destroy]&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;0&quot; /&gt;&lt;input id=&quot;bill_bill_items_attributes_new_bill_items__destroy&quot; name=&quot;bill[bill_items_attributes][new_bill_items][_destroy]&quot; type=&quot;checkbox&quot; value=&quot;1&quot; /&gt;
&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;" id="bill_items_fields_blueprint" style="display: none"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: update where? server or client? If client; post source html not server code...we aren't server parsers

Comment: I thought about calculating on client side. But to be honest: it doesn't matter for me, how and where this is calculated. Sorry about the unreadable code - now i pasted my HTML Source Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest you not do this in the view, as you'll run into problems like you mention (needing to parse a value out of formatted output such as prices).

This is where a view model might be helpful, since you're trying to derive more values out of your models used for display.  A helper method might suffice, but depending on how complicated the logic is, you'll want to test it, and it's easy to test classes that aren't coupled to Rails.

Take a look at the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for a view model implementation for Rails.

This doesn't really address your question about how to integrate this with jQuery, but depending on your needs, you could dynamically update this form with ajax when things change.  You might also consider rendering the raw values you're interested in as data attributes on the form elements so you don't have to worry about stripping out formatting.

**EDIT** - Here's a way to embed raw values in a form element so it is easily parsed by jQuery

in Rails:

```
<%= f.text_field :foo, :data => {:price => "12.99"} %>
```

The rendered html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="bill[foo]" id="bill_foo" data-price="12.99" />
```

to parse this with jQuery:

```
var price = $("#bill_foo").data("price");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please give me an example for that solution? I'm quite new to web development at all and don't know how to handle that..

Comment: the problem for that solution is, that it doesn't work with dropdowns. I can calculate only the price of the article I had on loading the site.. and the next problem is: how to get all "bill_foo" of that page? Nested_Form is giving them a name like bill_bill_items_attributes_0_count, bill_bill_items_attributes_1_count, ..

Comment: if you give them a css class then you can fetch all of them with jQuery and loop over them to add up their values.

Comment: that sounds possible yes... one last question: how can i fetch the price of the current selected option (=Article)?

Comment: You can add the data attribute to each option tag (which means you'll probably have to forego using `collection_select` and write your own helper).  Then in jQuery:  `$(".dropdown option:selected").data("price")`